# Cannot add items to list in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365

I have added a List to my newly created page in the new SharePoint Online. It should be simple to add items but none of the guides I have read have matched up to what I am seeing on my screen.

I added the list to my page by hovering over the "+" and selecting "List":

[image]

This then gives me a list which says "Select a list to add to this page":

[image]

There is nothing to select. I can click the "Edit" button and adjust the size of the list, **but there are no buttons or options to add items to the list**.

The "Edit" window gives me 2 options: a size option and a "List" dropdown with nothing in it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How am I meant to add items to this list?

Comment: HI MSOACC, can you please check your site content, is there any list already created. if not please create a new one in the site content. then it will appear in your newly created page.

Comment: Yeah I've just figured it out; I posted an answer to the question myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, by fluke I managed to find the solution that had been alluding me. I'll post it here for anyone who stumbles upon this in future.

I was adding a List as a Web Part (as seen in the first image). This basically just displays an existing list. To create the *actual* like you need to click the Settings Cog > Site Contents. In Site Contents you can click "New > List":

[image]

*Then* you can go to the List on your page, click Edit and select the newly created list from the dropdown:

[image]

Hope this helps anyone having the same issue.